# Install a python package for all users without messing with the system python installation

Tags: python, pipenv

I would like to install [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) onto a machine so that all users of that machine can use it, but I also don't want to mess with the system Python setup.

I can run `sudo pip install pipenv` but that goes ahead and changes the version of a bunch of packages installed in the system Python (I am using Scientific Linux 7.4). I would rather keep the system Python exactly as supplied by my linux distro (as I have read that messing with the system Python is a bad idea as core system tools may rely on it being a certain way).

I can do `pip install --user pipenv` but then only my user can use pipenv.

So two questions:

**1. Am I being unnecessarily afraid of modifying the system Python? Is it actually fine to update packages within the system Python?**

**2. If my caution is justified, what is the best way to `pip install` things (i.e. tooling such as Pipenv) for all users without modifying the system Python?**

I'd ideally like users to just be able to use pipenv by typing `pipenv`, not having to execute a file located in an obscure directory.

P.S. The ideal situation would be that pipenv was available as a 'safe' package from my distro, but alas it is not. I am also aware of virtualenvs, but my impression those are more for development and deployment of specific projects and not necessarily ideal for system-wide tooling (though I am prepared to be corrected on that).

Comment: I find Anaconda to be a good solution, since it exists in user space you/other users can install whatever you want and not affect System Python at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can never be too afraid of modifying the system Python. Your caution is justified.

I’d suggest you let all users share a global (but non-system) Python installation, either from the official distribution, Anaconda, pyenv’s python-build, or self-compiled source. Each user can then either perform their own `pip install --user` to their respective home directories, or you can, as an sudoer, install tools globally available to them, into the custom-managed, non-system, but global Python.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention that you may also do this with virtual environments and symlinks. An example for Pipenv (you can change paths as you prefer):

```
python3 -m venv /opt/venvs/pipenv
/opt/venvs/pipenv/bin/pip install pipenv
ln -s /opt/venvs/pipenv/bin/pipenv /opt/bin/pipenv

python3 -m venv /opt/venvs/flake8
/opt/venvs/pipenv/bin/pip install flake8
ln -s /opt/venvs/pipenv/bin/flake8 /opt/bin/flake8
```

This way to can install multiple tools without them affecting each other. Also you can combine this with custom-managed Python for even more peace of mind.

Comment: Thank you, your first suggestion is what I ended up doing. I installed python36 and python36-pip from the IUS repo, and was able to happily install pipenv into that without messing with the system Python. You virtual env suggestion seems a good idea if I had more tools to install.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use Anaconda and look up its documentation on how to use conda environments. Another plus is you can take your environment with you to use on any machine and it makes documenting package versions in your development workflow much easier and clear. Enjoy!

Comment: Unfortunately Anaconda is not free any more for companies with a certain size. 
And honestly I regard pipenv as the better alternative right now. Even the redeployments of environments is more deterministic and smoother.

Comment: `Penv` and/or `direnv` are definitely my modern preferences. I use mini forge nowadays instead of anoconda just to get around the bloat.